# How to remove an old deleted GCP organization from gcloud output?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I used to be part of a GCP organization. Then I had myself removed from that organization. Basically, I had the organization owner remove me from their IAM.

But when I do `gcloud organizations list`, I still see the old organization in the output along with my current one. Can someone please tell me what do I need to do for it to not show up in the output?

Because of this, I'm not able to run some of my custom bash scripts that query the organization name in the beginning.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: That means you still have access of some kind. Consider creating a different question to solve your bash script problem as having access to multiple organizations should not break correctly written scripts.

Comment: You have to recheck with the organization owner if your role shows up after repeated deletion attempts. If your role is custom it can be undeleted before 7 days then it permanently gets deleted maybe you should wait for that [period](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/organizations.roles/delete). In the meantime , create another role that suits your bash script requirements.